# Instead of username bash-4.2$ is displayed. How can I resolved that?

Tags: bash, prompt

After connecting to the server through SSH command in Linux `ssh: IP address`. In my server terminal changed to `bash-4.2$`.

If I try to connect from Putty in windows it connects but shows this `-bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied` and terminal opens as `bash-4.2$` instead of the username.

Comment: Are you connecting to a server that you are also the administrator on? The error suggests that someone has changed the permissions and/or ownership of `/etc/profile`, a file that `bash` uses when it starts.

Comment: Ditto Kusalananda's comments and: setting up a ~/.bash_profile with your desired PS1 seems reasonable. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `~/.bash` permissions have been changed or it might have some error.

Comment: The question mentions issues reading `/etc/profile`, not some file in the user's home directory.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command in your terminal to fix this issue:

```
export PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

Comment: The _issue_ is the wrong permissions on `/etc/profile`. If you're setting `PS1`, you definitely do not need to export it. It should be a shell variable, not an environment variable.

Comment: @Kusalananda this is not always the case. I had a different problem where `case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*)` in _.bashrc_ was no satisfied. Setting `PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '` resolved the issue. Thanks @abhay kumar

Comment: @igor 1) There is an issue with permissions on `/etc/profile`. This is clear from the error message present in the question. 2) Exporting `PS1` is never necessary. 3) Your issue is obviously different from the issue in the question and is quite possibly due to a wrongly set `TERM` variable. 4) A wrongly set `TERM` variable is not the same as the wrong permissions on `/etc/profile`, which this question is about.